# How to Protect Sensible Passwords stored in a Database

Tags: database, passwords, encryption

I'm developing a web application for which final users have to create an account. This part is very easy: I'll hash their passwords with SHA-256 so that nobody, except the user himself, knows the password. Now comes the difficult part. After the user creates an account, he/she has to provide the password of his/her email server. Now the question is: how can I protect this password decently (the password will be stored in a database)? If I encrypt the password with TripleDES, any developer or system administrator would be able to decrypt the password and see it. What is the usual way to deal with such a problem? Many Thanks.

Comment: Developers should not have access to production database.

Comment: Probably, you are not in control which email servers the users use, but for cases like this, where a user wants a 2nd party (you) to access some of his resources, hosted by a 3rd party (the user's mail server), without reveiling the 3rd-party-password, 3-legged-oauth was invented

Answer (score 10):

The usual way to do this is to use an symmetric encryption key which is derived from the user's password. The standard way to do this is using the algorithm specified in [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt), which generates a set of cryptographically secure bytes you can use as a key and IV. It's probably supported by a library for your language, .NET for example, which is what I use has the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) class.

Of course when your user changes their password you will have to decrypt any existing cipher text and then derive the new key and re-encrypt.

Comment: The link to the class is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx.

Comment: Caveat: this means you need to transmit the user's password from the client to the server, so the connection must be secure.  One of the advantages of hashing passwords is that you can hash the user's entry on the client machine, and then transmit only the hash to the server.  But, assuming a secure connection, blowdart's suggestion has the tremendous advantage of using a different encryption key for each user's data, greatly reducing the threat of compromise.

Comment: Well usually you *are* transmitting the user's password from the client to the server, but once it reaches the server you are then hashing it for the comparison. So what you'd do is at the same time as hashing for password checks you'd derive the key and place it in session state on the server so you can use it throughout the user's session.

Comment: Why would you use symmetric encryption instead of a cryptographic hash?  During login, you rehash the provided input and compare it to the stored salted hash; if there's a match, you approve login.  Then a sysadmin or developer can't decrypt a user's password, but it can be changed.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out; I didn't read closely enough that the OP needs the original cleartext for accessing a third-party account.  Ignore me.